# ORA-12840: cannot access a remote table after parallel/insert direct load txn After Switching To Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

We are encountering a strange issue at work.

For years we had a .NET Framework Windows service running with the Unmanaged Oracle Client (10.1.3001) with no problems at all.

Recently, we decided to upgrade that service and decided to use the latest Oracle Managed DataAccess (21.10.0 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/21.10.0#versions-body-tab).

We faced no problems with this migration so far, except from an issue with a procedure that uses a PARALLEL hint and accesses a remote table via a DB Link. This Oracle exception is thrown:

ORA-12840: cannot access a remote table after parallel/insert direct load txn

We have solved that problem by inserting some commit statements in the procedure, but we can't understand why the Driver change caused that behavior.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Perhaps the autocommit behaviour is now different?

Comment: @mustaccio How can I check that ?